# Jersey Spring Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/hk2/HK2InjectionManager

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

We are migrating an old project to maven based build, but while upgrading to Spring4 and Jersery spring integration I keep getting the below exception while starting the tomcat7.0.57, and I am not sure which jar i missing or causing this, exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/hk2/HK2InjectionManager
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:79)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 34 more
```

My spring and jersey jars:

Jersey Verion -- 2.26-b05

```
    <!-- Jersey Jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey Media -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Jars -->
```

Spring version -- 
     4.0.6.RELEASE

```
 <!-- Spring Jars -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a specific jersey version in one of dependency:

org.glassfish.jersey.ext
            jersey-spring3
            2.26-b03

instead of using `${jersey.version}`

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
```

Comment: //.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-spring3/2.26/jersey-spring3-2.26.jar (No such file or directory). The doesn't exist in this version of jersey.

Comment: It exists https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3/2.26-b03

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the precise problem is jersey-hk2 dependency needs to be 2.26. Changing that solved the problem.