# HK2InjectionManager with jersey, upgrading with OpenJDK11

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, java-11, spring-jersey

Ran into a few errors as I am upgrading jdk11 and jersey but this one particularly stumped. So jersey 2.28 is supposedly compatible with OpenJDK11 and fixed some issues that was previously in 2.25.1, so I upgraded it

I also saw this already, not a working solution - [Jersey Spring Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/hk2/HK2InjectionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170830/jersey-spring-maven-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-glassfish-jersey-hk2-hk2)

In my gradle build, failed on this task:

`> Task :ods-impl:test FAILED`

Under my task for this, here is the list of dependencies

```
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '2.28'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-spring3', version: '2.26-b03'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.28'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-multipart', version: '2.28'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: property('rev.commons-lang')
```

So then I encountered a new error with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/hk2/HK2InjectionManager

    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator.bindProvidersAndResources(ResourceModelConfigurator.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator.init(ResourceModelConfigurator.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:258)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainer.<init>(JettyHttpContainer.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerProvider.createContainer(JettyHttpContainerProvider.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(JettyHttpContainerFactory.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jetty.JettyTestContainerFactory$JettyTestContainer.<init>(JettyTestContainerFactory.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jetty.JettyTestContainerFactory$JettyTestContainer.<init>(JettyTestContainerFactory.java:45)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.jetty.JettyTestContainerFactory.create(JettyTestContainerFactory.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:584)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 54 more
```

So I added this dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '2.28'
```

However, I am still encountering that same error message, is there something wrong with how the dependencies matches up? I see it resolved the hk2 here in IntelliJ

[image]

Further digging I noticed that HK2InjectionManager on SpringComponentProvider is importing from the wrong path versus the location from the Hk2 dependency

Correct path from Jersey:
import org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory;

Path from Spring:
import org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out jersey-spring3 is outdated. If you want to use 2.27+ Jersey with Spring, but change dependency to use jersey-spring4

`compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-spring4', version: '2.28'`